# Los archivos de mi proyecto Android han desaparecido

Tags: android, android-studio

Ayer he formateado mi windows. Guardaba mi proyecto en `D:\AndroidStudioProjects` 
Hoy he instalado Android Studio en mi nuevo sistema operativo pero los "drawable" ni las clases del proyecto NO APARECEN

Solamente me aparece esto:

No entiendo que ha pasado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del directo `/app` estas abriendo el contenido de `/build` ahí no se encuentran los recursos si no archivos generados al compilar tu proyecto.

En este caso faltan los archivos que se encuentran dentro de `/src` y no existen en el proyecto me parece que en realidad fueron eliminados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas. Es un fallo mio, tenia que haber comprobado los archivos antes de formatear. Seguramente los archivos del proyecto se guardaron en C:\. De todas formas no entiendo porque Android Studio las guardo el C:\ cuando he especificado que se guardase en D:\AndroidStudioProjects

Comment: No se pueden guardar los archivos del proyecto en un drive y los archivos de /src dentro de otro. Lo que realizaste probablemente realizo esto.